# How to convert double quoted ids to single quoted ids so that it is queryable in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

PostgreSQL version: 10.3

**Schema of product**

```
id   integer
data text
```

**Schema of color**

```
id   integer
name text
```

Color of a product is stored within data as array of colorids ex: ['1','2'].

***I need a query wherein I could get the color id and name for a particular product.***
Tried something like this and got error:

```
select id,name from colors where id in (select  trim(data::json ->> 'color_ids','[]') from products where id = 1);
```

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = text

I tried this:

*query:*

```
select  data::json ->> 'color_ids' from products where id = 1;
```

*result:*

```
["2","5","6","14"]
```

*query:*

```
select  trim(data::json ->> 'color_ids','[]') from products where id = 1;
```

*result:*

```
"2","5","6","14"
```

Comment: Why isn't `data` a proper array column, e.g. `int[]`

Comment: To convert a JSON array to a table, you can use `json_array_elements_text`. But it is certainly better to use a better data type to store the data in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest making it a integer (int). Does it work when you put a replace around it?

```
replace (trim(data::json ->> 'color_ids','[]'), '"', '')
```